# c++ Ambiguous double nonvirtual function inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have a 2 classes:

```
struct a
{
    void test();
};

struct b
{
    void test();
};
```

Now let's inherit from those classes:

```
class c : public a, public b
{
};
```

Calling `c::test()` will generate an error, since `class a` and `class b` have the same function `void test()`, now my question:

Is it possible to inherit those (non-virtual!) functions, and when `c::test()` is called both are executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you need to implement `void test()` in `c`, and call both methods. There's no automatic way to do it.

```
class c : public a, public b
{
public:
    void test() {
        a::test();
        b::test();
    }
}
```

However, I would strongly discourage you from reimplementing non-virtual functions in derived classes. The problem is that the following would quietly call different functions, even though they operate on the same object:

```
   c* p1 = new c();
   a* p2 = p1;
   p1->test();
   p2->test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is wrong; inheriting from `a` and `b` is not an error. Trying to call `c::test()` is an error as its resolution is ambiguous. However, you can override `test()` in `c` however you like, for instance by explicitly calling `this->a::test();` and `this->b::test();` in `void c::test();`.